High voltage at main breaker
I have a 100amp breaker and one pole is reading 185 and the other is reading 57. Outlets are reading 185. Main power shutoff breaker on outside pole by meter keeps tripping the breaker.

Contact power company now.  You have a lost neutral.  Turn off/leave off main breaker till fixed(should be free).

Also be checking your house's ground rods/Grounding Electrode System... it's bad when you have a Lost Neutral and have to rely on ground rods to help control voltage balance, but I would expect it to do a better job than that.

You have a LOST NEUTRAL. This is a dangerous situation, because (a) your 120V stuff can't handle 185V and (b) the actual voltage on each half of the panel can go up and down unpredictably.
CALL YOUR UTILITY. A lost neutral is almost always an external problem and external problems are normally for the utility to fix. In most places they will come out for free and fix the problem quickly.
There is a very small possibility the problem is at or close to your panel, but relatively unlikely for a bunch of reasons.
If the utility doesn't know what a "lost neutral" is, just tell them you have an outage. Functionally the same in terms of the people and equipment needed to resolve it.
